# Jquery mobile swipe working but not changing image proper sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My mobile jquery image swipe is working properly but not maintaining sequentially.
When image is swiped the third image comes at second place and second image comes in third place.

find my codes below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="gal">
             <div class="grid">    
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                   <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                 </a>
               </div>

             <div class="grid">
                 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                   <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
                 </a>
              </div>

              <div class="grid">
                 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
                    <img class="zoom" src="https://i1.wp.com/demo.wpzoom.com/indigo/files/2013/04/volterman-smart-wallet-10.jpg?w=790&h=527&crop" alt="">
                 </a>  
               </div>

            <!--Images modal-->
               <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <!--image viewer-->
                      <div class="row">
                    <!---Prev Button-->
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a class="buttons_prev" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i>
                            </a> 
                         </div>
                          <!---next button-->    
                          <div class="col-1">
                              <a class="buttons_next" href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--- Image show-->
                         <div class="col-12">
                           <div class="image_post">
                            <ul align="center">

                               <li >
                                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"/>
                              <!--image wise details-->
                                 <div class="col-12">
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingA</h2>
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingB</h2>
                                    <p class="text-left">
                                      standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                    </p>
                                 </div> 
                                </li>  
                              <li>
                                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"/>
                              <!--image wise details-->
                                 <div class="col-12">
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingA</h2>
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingB</h2>
                                    <p class="text-left">
                                      standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                    </p>
                                 </div> 
                                </li> 
                            <li>
                                <img src="https://i1.wp.com/demo.wpzoom.com/indigo/files/2013/04/volterman-smart-wallet-10.jpg?w=790&h=527&crop"/>
                              <!--image wise details-->
                                 <div class="col-12">
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingA</h2>
                                   <h2 class="text-left">This is headingB</h2>
                                    <p class="text-left">
                                      standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                    </p>
                                 </div> 
                                </li> 



                             </ul>


                           </div> 
                            <!--image counter-->
                         <div align="center" class="slide_image_counter text-center">
                             <a></a>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                      <!--Image viewer-->  
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <!--Images modal-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.gal {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
     -moz-column-count: 3;
          column-count: 3;
          display: block;
          overflow: hidden;
}
.grid {
          overflow: hidden; 
          margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.zoom {
          cursor: pointer;
          transition: all .5s ease;
          transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid:hover .zoom {
          transform: scale(1.2);
}

.gal img {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
      .gal {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
      }
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.98);
  width: 100%;

}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;


}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:  -30px;
  right: -180px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*image like menu*/

.image_post ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.image_post ul li img{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;

}
.image_post ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.image_post ul li.activepostimg{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
/*image like menu*/
.buttons_prev,
.buttons_prev:hover
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons_next,
.buttons_next:hover
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons_prev i{

    margin-top: 20vh;

}
.buttons_next i{

    margin-top: 20vh;

}
.activepostimg h2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;

}
.activepostimg h2:nth-of-type(1){
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.activepostimg p{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.slide_image_counter{
    margin-top:-170px;
    color: white;
}
.slide_image_counter a{
    background-color:rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.5);
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
 .modal-lg {
    max-width: 900px;
  }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var totalItems = $('.image_post li').length, currentIndex = 1;
$('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');

//code for opening image
$('.grid img').on('click', function() {
    currentIndex = $('.grid img').index(this) + 1;
    $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
    $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
    $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
});

//code for next image  
$('.buttons_next').on('click', function() {
    if($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() < ($('.image_post li').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').next('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');  
    } else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
    }
});

//code for previous
$('.buttons_prev').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() > 0) {
            currentIndex--;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').prev('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');
    } else {
        currentIndex = $('.image_post li').length;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
    }
});

//swipe
        $("li").swiperight(function() {  
        if($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() < ($('.image_post li').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').next('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');  
        } else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
        }
        });

        $("li").swipeleft(function() {  
        if ($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').prev('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');
        } else {
        currentIndex = $('.image_post li').length;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
        }
        });

});
```

Everything works fine but the third image comes after swiping the first image.1st 2nd 3rd is not main taing properly.Help me

Answer (score 1):

Code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var totalItems = $('.image_post li').length, currentIndex = 1;
$('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');

//code for opening image
$('.grid img').on('click', function() {
    currentIndex = $('.grid img').index(this) + 1;
    $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
    $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
    $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
});

//code for next image  
$('.buttons_next').on('click', function() {
    if($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() < ($('.image_post li').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').next('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');  
    } else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
    }
});

//code for previous
$('.buttons_prev').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() > 0) {
            currentIndex--;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').prev('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');
    } else {
        currentIndex = $('.image_post li').length;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
    }
});

//swipe
        $("li").swiperight(function() {  

        if ($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').prev('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');
        } else {
        currentIndex = $('.image_post li').length;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
        }

        });

        $("li").swipeleft(function() { 

        if($('.image_post li.activepostimg').index() < ($('.image_post li').length - 1)){
        currentIndex++;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $('.activepostimg').removeClass('activepostimg').next('.image_post li').addClass('activepostimg');  
        } else {
        currentIndex = 1;
        $('.slide_image_counter a').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
        $(".image_post li").removeClass("activepostimg");
        $('.image_post li').eq(currentIndex - 1).addClass('activepostimg')
        }

        });

});
```